# Recoding (unequal number of) dates nested within (100k+) user IDs

Tags: r, dataset

I have a sufficiently large dataset and am refamilizaring myself with the features available in R. Here's a subset of the dataset. Date variables are coded correctly.

```
UID    date
104   2020-08-03 03:18:45
104   2020-09-08 05:18:26
104   2020-10-06 03:35:12
127   2020-07-04 03:18:45
132   2020-10-09 04:33:21
132   2020-11-05 02:28:38
...
```

I want a code to indicate which ordered date within individual is indicated. So it should look like this:

```
UID    date                 treatment
104   2020-08-03 03:18:45  1
104   2020-09-08 05:18:26  2
104   2020-10-06 03:35:12  3
127   2020-07-04 03:18:45  1
132   2020-10-09 04:33:21  1
132   2020-11-05 02:28:38  2
...
```

The code indicates a sort of "treatment number". Of course they all start on different months/days of the month and continue for different amounts of time. I've tried every combination of order, mutate, group_by, etc. but I'm struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (The word's *pore over*, anyway.) Mention which previously answered question came closest and where it falls short to be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, treatment := rowid(UID)]
```

Comment: this was very helpful! Even if i had multiple rows for each unique id + date combination, I created a separate id file with just the unique ids/dates, applied this function, then inner_join back the recoded variable to the main data file. It's inefficient but works for me. Thanks!